# why sudo nohup in linux always open two same proecss?

Tags: php, linux, sudo, nohup

I have a PHP script, `test.php`. When I run `sudo nohup /xx/bin/php test.php` in linux, it always opens two processes:

1. `sudo nohup /xx/bin/php test.php`
2. `nohup /xx/bin/php test.php`

Why is that?
I don't want the second one, and how do I start only the first process with `sudo`?

**my linux :**
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393716/why-do-login-and-sudo-fork-a-child-process-and-not-exec-straight-away)

Comment: First process is `sudo`, second is `nohup`. So you must have two of them